# How to create a lookup function or VBA code which can return value against only first found result?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose, in Sheet1, I have an Order table

```
OrderNo.  ShipmentNo.  Rate
54321          AP2312
54321          AP2312
29781          AP2312
32181          AP2312
54321          AP2312
```

In sheet2, I have rate table

```
OrderNo.     Rate
S4321          65
```

the below table is the end result which I am trying to get by applying some kind of lookup based on sheet2 rate table

```
OrderNo.  ShipmentNo.  Rate
54321     AP2312       65
54321     AP2312       0
29781     AP2312       NA
32181     AP2312       NA
54321     AP2312       0
```

which means, the formula should return the value against only first found result viz. 54321 in this case.

Comment: VLOOKUP will return the first match. But for your case it seems you wish to prevent the lookup. This could be done by embedding it in a condition, like, "If the order number wasn't already looked up, then look it up now".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

On Sheet1
In C2

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),0),"NA")
```

Edit:
Or more correctly this

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),0),"NA")
```

Comment: You're welcome. I have added another formula. Please try that also.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA

First check if the record is the first one with below:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,A:A,-1)=ROW(),1,0)
```

Then return your vlookup value:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,A:A,-1)=ROW(),VLOOKUP(A2,H:I,2,0),0)
```

Assuming `OrderNo` is in `A` column and your second table is in `H1:I2` of same sheet